# calling C program function in python - Segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes, digital-persona-sdk

So I have a C program that I am running from Python. But am getting segmentation fault error. when I run the C program alone, it runs fine. The C program interfaces a fingerprint sensor using the fprint lib.

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libfprint/fprint.h>



int main(){

struct fp_dscv_dev **devices;
struct fp_dev *device;
struct fp_img **img;

int r;
r=fp_init();

if(r<0){
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}

devices=fp_discover_devs();
if(devices){
    device=fp_dev_open(*devices);

    fp_dscv_devs_free(devices);
}
if(device==NULL){
    printf("NO Device\n");
    return 1;
}else{
    printf("Yes\n");
   
}


int caps;

caps=fp_dev_img_capture(device,0,img);

printf("bloody status %i \n",caps);

    //save the fingerprint image to file. ** this is the block that 
     causes the segmentation fault.

    int imrstx;
    imrstx=fp_img_save_to_file(*img,"enrolledx.pgm");
    fp_img_free(*img);


fp_exit();
return 0;
}
```

the python code

```
from ctypes import *
so_file = "/home/arkounts/Desktop/pythonsdk/capture.so"
my_functions = CDLL(so_file)

a=my_functions.main()
print(a)
print("Done")
```

The capture.so is built and accessed in python. But calling from python, I get a Segmentation fault. What could be my problem?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I am unfamiliar with [libfprint](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-stable/), after taking a look at your code and comparing it with the documentation, I see two issues with your code that can both cause a segmentation fault:

---

**First issue:**

According to the [documentation of the function `fp_discover_devs`](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-stable/libfprint-Device-discovery.html#fp-discover-devs), `NULL` is returned on error. On success, a NULL-terminated list is returned, which may be empty.

In the following code, you check for failure/success, but don't check for an empty list:

```
devices=fp_discover_devs();
if(devices){
    device=fp_dev_open(*devices);

    fp_dscv_devs_free(devices);
}
```

If `devices` is non-NULL, but empty, then `devices[0]` (which is equivalent to `*devices`) is NULL. In that case, you pass this NULL pointer to `fp_dev_open`. This may cause a segmentation fault.

I don't think that this is the reason for your segmentation fault though, because this error in your code would only be triggered if an empty list were returned.

---

**Second issue:**

The last parameter of [`fp_dev_img_capture`](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-stable/libfprint-Devices-operations.html#fp-dev-img-capture) should be a pointer to an **allocated** variable of type `struct fp_img *`. This tells the function the address of the variable that it should write to. However, with the code

```
struct fp_img **img;
[...]
caps=fp_dev_img_capture(device,0,img);
```

you are passing that function a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), because `img` does not point to any valid object. This can cause a segmentation fault as soon as the wild pointer is dereferenced by the function or cause some other kind of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), such as overwriting other variables in your program.

I suggest you write the following code instead:

```
struct fp_img *img;
[...]
caps=fp_dev_img_capture(device,0,&img);
```

Now the third parameter is pointing to a valid object (to the variable `img`).

Since `img` is now a single pointer and not a double pointer, you must pass `img` instead of `*img` to the functions `fp_img_save_to_file` and `fp_img_free`.

This second issue is probably the reason for your segmentation fault. It seems that you were just "lucky" that your program did not segfault as a standalone program.